# Why my iAd banner not showing on my gameView?

Tags: iphone, swift, sprite-kit, iad, banner

I just finished my first game and I'm trying this code on my viewController to integrate  an ad banner :

```
import iAd

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var skView = self.originalContentView as SKView
    var scene:SKScene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)

    skView.showsFPS = false
    skView.showsNodeCount = false
    skView.showsPhysics = false


    let turbulence = SKFieldNode.turbulenceFieldWithSmoothness(0.1, animationSpeed: 0.1)
    scene.addChild(turbulence)
    let noise = SKFieldNode.turbulenceFieldWithSmoothness(0.4, animationSpeed: 0.1)
    scene.addChild(noise)

    skView.presentScene(scene)

    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
}
```

On my firstViewController (the game presentation) it works but not on my gameViewController and I can't understand why.

Someone can help me ?

Thank you all !!!

Comment: Do both view controllers have their own SKView? If so, you're creating two views which is not supported on iOS. Use one view controller for excatly one SKView, and if you need more "controllers" put that code in the respective SKScene subclass.

Comment: Actually I have 3 SKView and their own view controllers. So 3 views and 3 view controllers.

Comment: Well you can only have one active SKView at a time. To transition between scenes you should be using SKTransition, not presenting new view controllers with new views.